# Flutter scrollable positioned list issue

Tags: flutter

I use [scrollable positioned list pacakge](https://pub.dev/packages/scrollable_positioned_list) to navigate between widgets from bottom to top, and when adding each element I give it a controller and add it to the list as shown in the code below.

The code works fine for me when I move slowly between the items (Widgets), but when I move quickly, the exception appears as it is.

I hope someone can help me solve this.

**List of ItemScrollController**

```
List<ItemScrollController> itemsScrollControllers = [];
```

**initState**

```
@override
  void initState() {
    addComponentsToHomeList(listOfContent);
    super.initState();
  }
```

**Function**

```
  List<Widget> addComponentsToHomeList(List<ContentModel> content) {

      for (var index = 0; index < content.length; index++) {
        var itemContent = content[index];

        ItemScrollController itemScrollController = ItemScrollController();

        switch (itemContent.itemsTheme) {
          case 'continue_watch':
            if (itemContent.items!.isNotEmpty) {
              itemsScrollControllers.add(itemScrollController);
              /*
              code...
              */
            }
            break;
          case 'poster_with_number':
            if (itemContent.items!.isNotEmpty) {
              itemsScrollControllers.add(itemScrollController);
              /*
              code...
              */
            }
        }
    }
    setState(() {});
    return homeComponents;
  }
```

**Implimntion when scroll**

```
 itemsScrollControllers[positionY].scrollTo(
                    index: positionX,
                    alignment: 0.20, 
                    curve: Curves.fastOutSlowIn,
                    duration: const Duration(milliseconds: 500), 
                  );
```

**Exception**

```
Unhandled Exception: 'package:scrollable_positioned_list/src/scrollable_positioned_list.dart': Failed assertion: line 236 pos 12: '_scrollableListState != null': is not true.
```

Answer (score 0):

My Friend, the exception that you get is because of `_scrollableListState` is null when you want to scroll quickly because the widget tree is not built completly. anyway you can use `SchedulerBinding` to make you execute after the widget tree is built completly:

```
import 'package:flutter/scheduler.dart' show SchedulerBinding;

// in your scroll method:
SchedulerBinding.instance!.addPostFrameCallback((_) {
  itemsScrollControllers[positionY].scrollTo(
    index: positionX,
    alignment: 0.20, 
    curve: Curves.fastOutSlowIn,
    duration: const Duration(milliseconds: 500),
  );
});
```

happy coding...